# How to change the css so that this particular attachment form is displayed properly

Tags: sharepoint-server, css, visual-studio-2013

In SharePoint 2013 after migration from SharePoint 2010, the **launch form dialogue box is selected yes**  in advanced list settings.

[image]

So the Edit form for each item opens as a form and there is an attachment icon on this edit form. So when the attachment is clicked an attachment form is opened and displayed as shown in image below.

[image].

But it has to be displayed as shown in the below image.
[image]

The **classes, id's and pagetype are same** for edit form and attachment form.
Can anyone suggest me how to make the changes as it is repeated to all the lists in the site.

**We do not use SharePoint designer**. The site is a customized one developed by using Visual Studio.